# Than as modifier

Tags: modifiers

In this sentence, does "than his father" modify the entire phrase "better player"? He was a better player than his father.

Answer (score 3):

*than his father* is not a modifier but the complement of the comparative adjective *better*.<sup>†</sup>

The comparative construction *-er* .. *than his father* modifies the adjective *good*, and the resultant AP *better than his father* modifies *player*.

---

<sup>†</sup> If you want to get really fancy you could say that it's the complement of the comparative suffix *-er* (just as it would be the complement of the comparative adverb *more* in *more active than his father*), or that it's the complement of the 'feature' comparative grade written out as *-er*.